# Why JSON.stringify('production')?

Tags: webpack

In the [Webpack Production Documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/production/#specify-the-environment), one recommendation is to instantiate the object with a configuration variable for process.env.NODE_ENV, with the following recommended code:

```
+     new webpack.DefinePlugin({
+       'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
+     })
```

Why `JSON.stringify('production')` and not just merely `'production'`?

Comment: To ensure it's a valid JSON object.  It ends up encapsulating the string in quotes.

Comment: But 'production' is also that string encapsulated in quotes. Why the extra code to get the same thing?

Comment: Probably because it's a widely used project and they want to ensure forward compatibility.

Comment: How is a quoted string going to become incompatible?

Comment: It's an environment variable to the process.  They could change it in the future, or users can change it.  They're keeping it valid json for serialization (probably).

Comment: It's not reading an env var. It's "stringifying" a string.

Comment: That string could potentially be whatever you want it to be.

Comment: By this logic, programmers should `JSON.stringify()` any string they are using in any Javascript object, even a string literal as shown in the example, which is not how people actually do it.

Comment: I was playing devil's advocate for why they could've made that decision. Without reading the documentation commit notes I guess you won't really know

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer elsewhere in the webpack docs.

According to [the define-plugin docs](https://github.com/webpack/webpack.js.org/blob/fd37f672cc157ed33df119424e23cb53a2141dc6/src/content/plugins/define-plugin.md#usage), you must supply a string with quotes embedded.

> T> Note that because the plugin does a direct text replacement, the value given to it must include actual quotes inside of the string itself. Typically, this is done either with either alternate quotes, such as '"production"', or by using JSON.stringify('production').

Thanks TheIncorrigible1 for the Monday banter.

Comment: I think it was a mistake for their docs to suggest `JSON.stringify()` on `'production'` or any other literals. It's much more verbose and potentially confusing (which led to the original question) than `'"production"'` or `'"true"'`, where the quotes are clearly intentional.